# Plot a raster using hexes in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis

I have a GIS raster data frame that I would like to plot using hexagonal tiles. The standard method using tile_geom() is straightforward:

```
ggplot(raster_df, aes(x, y, fill=blabla)) + geom_tile()
```

Howewer, I would really like my raster points to be displayed as hexes instead of rects for aesthetic reasons. The end result should be something like in this blog post: http://www.statsblogs.com/2014/09/02/how-to-create-a-hexagonal-bin-plot-in-sas/

I tried using geom_hex() instead of geom_tile(), but because geom_hex() seems to be intended with binning in mind, I can't figure out how to hack it to display my data instead. I would like for every raster point to correspond to a hex, i.e. have no binning at all!

Thank you for any suggestions.

Edit: as requested, here is a sample data raster (its actually very close to what I am using, as I want to plot a world map and colour each raster point according to a custom statistic)

```
library(maptools)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

data('wrld_simpl')
raster_df <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(rasterize(wrld_simpl, raster(res=5))))
raster_df$blabla <- rnorm(nrow(raster_df))
```

Comment: Link to or a `dput` of part of the data perchance?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though this might be due to the implementation of `geom_hex` in `ggplot2`. I've used this package for a few years, and my first guess is to try:

```
ggplot(raster_df, aes(x, y, fill=blabla)) + geom_hex(stat="identity")
```

But this throws an error:

```
Error in ggplot2:::hexGrob(x = raster_df$x, y = raster_df$y, fill = raster_df$blabla) : 
could not find function "hexcoords"
```

So I looked for the function `hexcoords`, which appears in the `hexbin` package. I explicity load that package and try again:

```
library(hexbin)
ggplot(raster_df, aes(x, y, fill=blabla)) + geom_hex(stat="identity")
```

And that works. The result isn't particularly beautiful, so it might be better to use the `hexbin` package a little more directly.

It doesn't seem that geom_hex() was designed to directly plot the data to hexagons without the interim step of `stat = "binhex"`, which is different from many of the other `geom_` functions.